# Using Mass Assignment Shoulda Matchers in Rspec with Rails 2.3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, shoulda

[Shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) for Rspec do not support allow_mass_assignment_of for ActiveRecord classes.

As a workaround, would you regard the following code as equivalent?

```
it { should_not allow_mass_assignment_of :id }

it { MyClass.protected_attributes.include?("id").should be_true }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code, both are equivalent, but the first line should work correctly.
You can check it on https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_mass_assignment_of_matcher.rb

Answer (score 1):

I too am experiencing this problem.  The following test:

```
it should allow_mass_assignment_of(:email)
```

fails with the error message

```
undefined method 'allow_mass_assignment_of' for #<Class:0x1044de9c8> (NoMethodError)
```

while the following test succeeds (thus establishing that Shoulda is present):

```
it should validate_uniqueness_of(:email)
```

shoulda-matchers version 1.0.0, rspec (and all related gems) version 2.8.0

It doesn't seem like it, but could this somehow be related to this issue: https://github.com/mergulhao/shoulda-matchers/commit/3a75c6877c07fbf62e77b1fb0aa852138bd537d6